# How to determine the order in which AABB boxes should be drawn on this projection?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, 3d, algebra

Using the following projection:

```
[x,y] = [x - z*sqrt(2)/2, y - z*sqrt(2)/2]
```

And a scene with some AABB boxes [x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1], you get this result:

[image]

(note: sides of boxes are not drawn! Those are boxes, not squares. There are 5 boxes on top of 13x13 boxes)

What is a sorting function that will organize those boxes in the correct order in which they should be drawn?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question, but what is wrong with sorting by z coordinate?

Comment: Just by Z coordinate? It won't work. For example, suppose there is a box at the position [5,5] - that is, to the left of that podium on the middle. Suppose it is at a slightly higher Z. Sorting by Z will make it be drawn after the podium, while it is supposed to be drawn before! (it is behind it on the projection)

Comment: @arghbleargh or easier: this is the result of sorting by z position: http://o7.no/146ithL

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean by the sides not being drawn now. It seems like what you want is not possible then... (see answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on drawing each box all in one go, then I think what you are trying to do is fundamentally impossible. Consider the boxes

```
(0.9, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.9, 1.1, 2.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.9, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.1)
```

They obscure each other in a cycle, so there's no order of drawing them that will work.